# Assistance using an API using a php tpl file

Tags: php, api, content-management-system

I am going to level with you guys/gals. I have never used an API that I haven't copied and pasted from google/twitter etc.

I have a tpl file written in php code. Within this tpl file I have a section that relates to a review counter. (So how many reviews this product on this page has been submitted)

I am trying to replace this 'native counter' for the cms:

```
<?php echo $reviews; ?> <img align="absmiddle" class="fade-image" src="catalog/view/theme/simplegreat/image/stars-<?php echo $rating; ?>.png" alt="<?php echo $reviews; ?>" /></div>
```

I am wanting this code which returns the review from the native review system, with the API for a third party review system. The system is in place where it needs to be, however I need to implement their API to grab the review count and rating from their 3rd party server.

So the API I am trying to use is: [HERE](http://docs.yotpoapi.apiary.io/#get-/products/%7Bapp_key%7D/%7Bsku%7D/bottomline?callback=%7Bpjson_callback%7D)

So I am trying to use this API to output the following:

- Number of reviews eg. '8 reviews'
- The average rating in the form of stars. It should do this automatically as it does in the main review section in the page.

If someone could help me through this API and hopefully I can learn a little more about APIs with php and how they function in the process.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite easy, just follow the documentation :-)

The documentation states:

> `/products/{app_key}/{sku}/bottomline?callback={pjson_callback}`
>
> Given `product_sku` (unique identifier of the product within your
>   domain), and a `app_key`, the call returns the total reviews and average
>   score of this product.
>
> Required params:
>
> `appkey` - the app key of the account sku - id of the product in the
>   website, should be consistent with the product_id that is used in the
>   product page
>
> Optional params: `callback` - jsonp call back function

They even give you an example in PHP:

**Request** (this is how you use the API)

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://yotpoapi.apiary.io/products/{app_key}/{sku}/bottomline?callback={pjson_callback}");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json"));
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

var_dump($response);
```

**Response** (This is what you'll get back)

```
200 (OK)
    Content-Type: application/json


{
   "status":{
      "code":200,
      "message":"OK"
   },
   "response":{
      "bottomline":{
         "average_score":4.52,
         "total_reviews":23
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: So how would I use this response to output what I want. In this case, I want the total number of reviews. So >> Reviews (23) << for example. This is where I am confused. I am not sure how to use the response.

Comment: Well, do you know how to parse JSON? If not, please follow a tutorial on that :)